# Size of Column store index on Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I copied a row-based table with about 90 million rows into a column store index Table.

The decrease rate of the table was acceptable. But I want the size of column store index.

The `sp_spaceused` procedure didn't give any result for the column-based table. How can we get the size of the index?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With a clustered columnstore index, the data and index are one and the same so the reported data size includes both data and index.

A traditional b-tree clustered index also has non-leaf index pages which is reported separately by the index space.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID ) TableName,
       i.name IndexName,
       SUM(s.used_page_count) / 128.0 IndexSizeinMB
FROM sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS S
     ON i.OBJECT_ID = S.OBJECT_ID AND I.index_id = S.index_id
WHERE i.name = 'YOUR_INDEX_NAME'
GROUP BY i.OBJECT_ID, i.name
```

Or if you have several indexes, you can skip the WHERE condition